# with not a lot of choices

Tags: prepositions, negation

a. He owned a small bookshop with not a lot of choices.

b. I travelled in Europe with not a lot of money.

c. With not a lot of time left, I had to do things rapidly.

Are the above sentences grammatically correct?

Comment: I believe those are accurate. As in 'I should point out that not one of these painting is original.', The adverb 'not' modifies a determiner 'one', so the 'not' also modifies 'a lot'.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, yes, they are correct. In practice, I doubt anyone in the USA would use those sentences to express those ideas.

A more natural expression of #1 could be "He owned a small bookshop with few choices."
However, even that sentence is slightly ambiguous - choices of what? Most likely books, of course, but it's not great to make the reader work for that conclusion. Perhaps a better rewrite would be "He owned a small bookshop with a meagre selection."

A more natural expression of #2 could be "I travelled in Europe with only a little money". In this case, 'little' is not being used exactly as a measure of size, it's being used as in the phrase "I have only a little bread" - To express a very small quantity of something.

#3 is the closest to a natural expression, but could be more naturally expressed as "With little time left, I had to do things rapidly." Similar to #2, "little" is being used to express a very small amount.